# I want to catch collision between collision between (mouse) cursor and sprite using phaser

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, phaser-framework, mouse-cursor

So like, here's the code. I'm really new to all of this, but I wanted to try something like *this* out for a project I'm assigned at school.

```
'use strict'
const Game = new Phaser.Game(1920, 1080, Phaser.AUTO, 'game-canvas', { preload, create,update })

let player
let cursors
let speed
let cursor


Game.physics.arcade.enable()

function preload() {


Game.load.spritesheet('mechove','mechove.png',71/2,29/1)

}

function create() {
   
  player = Game.add.sprite(Game.width/2, Game.height/2, 'mechove')
  
  player.scale.setTo(3,3)
  player.anchor.setTo(0.6,0.6)
  Game.physics.arcade.enable(player)
  player.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
  cursors=Game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys()
  player.body.allowRotation = false;
  player.frame = 1 
}

function update(){
  console.log(Game.input.activePointer.x)
  player.rotation = Game.physics.arcade.moveToPointer(player, 20, Game.input.activePointer, 1000);  
}
```

P.S. I want to detect collision between the cursor and the sprite 'mechove', because it's spritesheet consists of one bloody sword and one non-bloody, the idea is that when the sword-sprite touches the cursor the bloody one comes up.

Comment: which version of phaser, are you using?  _(doesn't seem like phaser 3)_ and do you mean collision between player and mechove? if not what is the cursor you are refering to?

Answer (score 0):

As winner_joiner pointed out, it looks like you're using Phaser 2. The way to achieve this interaction in Phaser 2 is:
First enable inputs on the player sprite (this is the case for any GameObject) using the .inputEnabled property:

```
player.inputEnabled = true;
```

Then, in the update() functon, you can continually check the pointerOver() function on the input property of player:

```
function update() {
    if (player.input.pointerOver()) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

[Here's an example](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/input/pointer-over) with code for this exact scenario. I highly recommend going through the [examples catalogue](https://phaser.io/examples/v2) when you want to figure out how to do something in Phaser. They help me a lot.

---

If using Phaser 3, you can detect the mouse cursor interacting with any GameObject (such as the `player` sprite) by calling the `.setInteractive()` function on player and creating a listener for the `'pointerover'` on the sprite:

```
player.setInteractive().on('pointerover', callbackHandleFunc)
```

[The input plugin documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Input.InputPlugin.html)

[The documentation specifically for the pointerover event for a GameObject](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Input.Events.html#event:GAMEOBJECT_POINTER_OVER)

Comment: I also recommend switching to Phaser 3 if you aren't using it. The examples and documentation are more fleshed out, and it should perform better. But for your project, I'm sure any version will work well